# Should I cut my raspberry cane that bloomed but they dried up before fruiting?

Tags: plant-care, pruning, vines, raspberries

My 3 yr old red raspberry bloomed and the flowers dried up due to weather/watering. I don't know what kind of raspberry plant it is. It's a bare root from Walmart. Should I cut the cane or will it bloom/produce again next year?

Comment: Raspberry canes seemingly come in 2 varieties, one you cut back right to the ground and the other you leave alone. Unless you know which variety you have, cutting them back this year may mean you get no crop next - a mistake I made 2 years ago. I had no fruit in 2022 but I have had plenty of berries this year. I intend to leave mine alone from now on lol.